# What to do when IDA does not recognize return value?

Tags: ida, hexrays

I have a function which fetches the Glide screen width and height and passes it to some set-up function (`sub_457048`).

However, IDA does not recognize that the Glide API function to retrieve the width obviously returns it:

[image]

This gets interesting when looking into the assembly code:
[image]

I'm not sure how to tell IDA the `grSstScreenWidth` returns a value into EBX which is then put in EDX: The set-up function looks correct - I never understood that useless mov of EAX into EBX after the height function was called; height stays in EAX, and width is put into EDX:

[image]

Am I wrong here? Is IDA wrong? Or is nobody wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to change the prototype of `_grSstScreenWidth()` to be a [`__usercall`](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/1361.shtml) function with the return value in `ebx`.

For example:

```
int __usercall _grSstScreenWidth@<ebx>()
```

Answer (score 1):

I am probably late for this, but for future visitors:
the parameters to sub_457048 are passed in eax and edx. The call to _grSstScreenHeight is returned in eax and then saved in ebx, and finally moved in edx.
The call to _grSstScreenWidth is returned in eax.

so sub_457048 will be eax (width) and edx (height) which is correct.

The intermediate step to store the value in ebx, is because it's not known to the caller if _grSstScreenWidth will overwrite edx (as it is allowed to, according to the STDCALL calling convention https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#stdcall). On the other hand, _grSstScreenWidth has to preserve ebx.

You're right however, IDA did not seem to see that the value returned by _grSstScreenWidth was to be stored in v4